# SimplePHPUnit Package on windows with Sublime Text 3

Tags: phpunit, sublimetext3

I am trying to use SimplePHPUnit package in Sublime Text 3, but when I am issuing the run command, it only and always returns:

```
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
[cmd: phpunit --stderr]
[dir: C:\Apache24\htdocs]
[path: ...]
```

phpunit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit 
colors="true"     
strict="false"      
bootstrap="phpUnitAutoload.php" 
verbose="true"> 
</phpunit>
```

Is this package suposed to be working on windows?  If so, any idea how to get it to work properly?

I am using phpunit-6.2.1 and php 7.0.6 on Windows 10

Comment: Try PHPUnitKit for Sublime Text 3 https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHPUnitKit, which should work out of the box, but is also highly configurable.

Answer (score 1):

My phpunit.cmd was not properly set or accessible in the PATH.  Hence it was not found by SimplePHPUnit.